# How to make a Twitter-like following system

Tags: php, mysql

How can i make a Twitter-like following system where, if you follow someone, you will receive their tweets. I have a database table called "users", "followings", and "posts". The users table holds the users that are on my site. The followings shows the persons followers, this table is setup like this :'id, user_one, user_two'. And the posts table holds all the tweets or posts that the unique user has.

I have a profile page set up for each user, with a follow button. And also I have a news feed for the user, but in that news feed I need it to show posts from users that the logged-in user is following. So is there anyway for me to have a user follow someone and receive the posts from that user on their news feed.

Now I [did some research](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-twitter-interface/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw9d&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grsitelnxw9d): their system wouldn't seem to work. I kept getting this error:

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in function.php on line 12

```sql
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  body, 
  stamp 
FROM posts 
WHERE user_id in () 
ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

> Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in function.php.

This line right here was suppose to help make it where when you follow that person you will receive there tweets and stuff

```php
function show_posts($userid,$limit=0){
$posts = array();

$user_string = implode(',', $userid);
$extra =  " and id in ($user_string)";

if ($limit > 0){
    $extra = "limit $limit";
}else{
    $extra = '';    
}

$sql = "select user_id,body, stamp from posts 
    where user_id in ($user_string) 
    order by stamp desc $extra";
echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $posts[] = array(   'stamp' => $data->stamp, 
                        'userid' => $data->user_id, 
                        'body' => $data->body
                );
}
return $posts;
```

}

I believe this piece of code, which is supposed to show posts from other users, is causing this problem but I don't know why.

Comment: Looks like your sql isn't valid and that results in an invalid array, so implode doesn't work. After `$fsql = ..` type `die($fsql);` and tell us what your sql statement is..

Comment: i have the link to it here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-twitter-interface/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw9d&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grsitelnxw9d

Comment: @artandmanga mattedgod is just being a troll. He knows ibm, and so does everyone else, hence his sarcasm..

Comment: function show_posts($userid,$limit=0){$posts = array();
 $user_string = implode(',', $userid);
 $extra =  " and id in ($user_string)";

 if ($limit > 0){
  $extra = "limit $limit";
 }else{
  $extra = ''; 
 }

 $sql = "select user_id,body, stamp from posts 
  where user_id in ($user_string) 
  order by stamp desc $extra";
 echo $sql;
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
  $posts[] = array(  'stamp' => $data->stamp, 
       'userid' => $data->user_id, 
       'body' => $data->body
     );
 }
 return $posts;

}   . This is the sql thats causing the error

Comment: what is the value of userid

Comment: @zod the value of userid is the users id number from my data base "users": source for all this is at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-twitter-interface/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw9d&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grsitelnxw9d

Comment: you dont have to provide url always :-) . try to print $userid  and $user_string . you are getting error at implode itself

Comment: Ohh ok and so it is from the implode part so try to echo or print the $userid and $user_string @zod

Answer (score 0):

Use a join. For example:

```sql
select user_id, text from posts
    inner join followings on posts.user_id = followings.followed_id
    where followings.follower_id = :user_id;
```

If I may recommend, stop using the `mysql_` functions; [they are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) and should not be used in newer applications. Instead, I'd recommend using [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo).